# Geolocation google api on a ruby on rails Site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps-api-3

I have a process on my ruby site that should pull geographical data and insert it into my locations table.

I did not program this. It was with the site when our company took over. I dont know alot about ruby or JSON/XML

```
  def self.check_unknown(cs)
    report = Report.first( :conditions => { :metric => "unknown_locations", :name => cs } )
    #i.e. if it's been tried 25 times, add it to the locations table.
    if report.value > 5
      city, state = cs.split(",")
      state = state.strip
      google_api_results = HTTParty.get("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=#{cs.gsub(/ /, "%20")}&sensor=true")
      geo_data = google_api_results.parsed_response
      lat = geo_data["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"]
      lng =  geo_data["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"]
      l = Location.new({ 
        :city => city,
        :state => state,
        :coords => "ST_GeographyFromText('POINT( #{lat} #{lng} )')"
      })
      l.save
      Report.delete(report.id)
      return l
    else
      return false
    end
  end
```

This is using the following table for information:

```
ID     NAME                        METRIC               VALUE    CREATED_AT                       UPDATED_AT
19  |  "Jenkinstownship, PA"  |  "unknown_locations"  |  89   |  "2013-01-17 05:22:25.603078"  |  "2013-01-27 16:49:38.642298"
23  |  "Evergreen, SC"        |  "unknown_locations"  |  154  |  "2013-01-17 05:22:52.280582"  |  "2013-03-25 18:46:21.642839"
24  |  "East Scio, OH"        |  "unknown_locations"  |  29   |  "2013-01-17 05:23:01.952421"  |  "2013-01-18 00:58:39.457106"
28  |  "Ft Collins, CO"       |  "unknown_locations"  |  134  |  "2013-01-17 05:23:34.109053"  |  "2013-04-02 02:45:16.37779"
```

Expose to insert data into locations table like:

```
ID          CORDS                                                   CITY               STATE    ZIP         CREATED                          UPDATED                          CS                    ALT
69640  |  "0101000020E6100000B5A679C729A255C0787AA52C430E4140"  |  "blountsville"  |  "al"  |  "35031"  |  "2012-05-31 11:00:34.269803"  |  "2012-05-31 11:00:34.269803"  |  "blountsville, al"  |  ""
69641  |  "0101000020E61000009D4B7155D9C155C09E0AB8E7F9F94040"  |  "bremen"        |  "al"  |  "35033"  |  "2012-05-31 11:00:34.278116"  |  "2012-05-31 11:00:34.278116"  |  "bremen, al"        |  ""
69642  |  "0101000020E610000020240B98C0CD55C0A6F10BAF24754040"  |  "brent"         |  "al"  |  "35034"  |  "2012-05-31 11:00:34.28644"   |  "2012-05-31 11:00:34.28644"   |  "brent, al"         |  ""
69643  |  "0101000020E6100000EDBB22F8DFBC55C083DA6FED44854040"  |  "brierfield"    |  "al"  |  "35035"  |  "2012-05-31 11:00:34.294715"  |  "2012-05-31 11:00:34.294715"  |  "brierfield, al"    |  ""
69644  |  "0101000020E61000006DAD2F12DABA55C0A1F831E6AED14040"  |  "brookside"     |  "al"  |  "35036"  |  "2012-05-31 11:00:34.303135"  |  "2012-05-31 11:00:34.303135"  |  "brookside, al"     |  ""
69645  |  "0101000020E6100000B9533A58FFAF55C08FFB56EBC48D4040"  |  "calera"        |  "al"  |  "35040"  |  "2012-05-31 11:00:34.311167"  |  "2012-05-31 11:00:34.311167"  |  "calera, al"        |  ""
69646  |  "0101000020E6100000EDBB22F8DFC855C0B2135E82537B4040"  |  "centreville"   |  "al"  |  "35042"  |  "2012-05-31 11:00:34.319782"  |  "2012-05-31 11:00:34.319782"  |  "centreville, al"   |  ""
69647  |  "0101000020E61000008638D6C56DAA55C03065E08096A84040"  |  "chelsea"       |  "al"  |  "35043"  |  "2012-05-31 11:00:34.328041"  |  "2012-05-31 11:00:34.328041"  |  "chelsea, al"       |  ""
```

But it is entering like this:

```
ID      CORDS     CITY             STATE    ZIP         CREATED                          UPDATED                     CS     ALT
8806  |  ""  |  "URBANCREST"    |  "OH"  |  ""  |  "2014-04-29 12:58:39.209943"  |  "2014-04-29 12:58:39.209943"  |  ""  |  ""
8807  |  ""  |  "north valmey"  |  "NV"  |  ""  |  "2014-04-29 13:19:23.996848"  |  "2014-04-29 13:19:23.996848"  |  ""  |  ""
8808  |  ""  |  "SAN SIMON"     |  "AZ"  |  ""  |  "2014-04-29 13:19:30.744791"  |  "2014-04-29 13:19:30.744791"  |  ""  |  ""
8809  |  ""  |  "COLUMBIA FALLS"|  "ID"  |  ""  |  "2014-04-29 13:19:30.789425"  |  "2014-04-29 13:19:30.789425"  |  ""  |  ""
```

WHOLE Locations model

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :city, :coords, :state, :zip
  set_rgeo_factory_for_column(:coords,  RGeo::Geographic.spherical_factory(:srid => 4326))

  def self.validate_cs_and_return_proper(location)
    return "ANYWHERE" if location.upcase == "ANYWHERE" || location.nil? || location == ""
    state = location[-2,2]
    city = location.gsub(%r(, [a-zA-Z]+), '').strip 
    l = first(:conditions => {:city => city.downcase, :state => state.downcase}) 
    if l.nil?
      new_l = where("(levenshtein(city, '#{city}') <= 4) AND state = '#{state}'").order("levenshtein(city, '#{city}') ASC").first
      return "#{new_l.city}, #{new_l.state}"
    else
      return location
    end
  end

  def self.city_state_exists?(location)
    return true if location.upcase == "ANYWHERE" || location.nil? || location == ""
    state = location[-2,2]
    city = location.gsub(%r(, [a-zA-Z]+), '').strip 
    l = first(:conditions => {:city => city.downcase, :state => state.downcase}) 
    if l.nil?
      new_l = where("(levenshtein(city, '#{city}') <= 4) AND state = '#{state}'").order("levenshtein(city, '#{city}') ASC").first
      return true unless new_l.blank?
      return false
    else
      return true
    end
  end

  def self.to_point(location)
    return location unless location.class == String
    return nil if location.upcase=='ANYWHERE'
    state = location[-2,2]
    city = location.gsub(%r(, [a-zA-Z]+), '').strip 
    l = first(:conditions => {:city => city.downcase, :state => state.downcase}) 
    l.coords
  end

  def self.to_cs(point)
    return "ANYWHERE" if point.nil? || (point.x == 0.0 && point.y == 0.0)
    l = first(:conditions => {:coords => point})
    l[:state] = l[:state].upcase
    c_parts = l[:city].split(" ")
    c_parts.each {|part| part.capitalize! }
    l[:city] = c_parts.join(" ") 
    return "#{l[:city]}, #{l[:state].upcase}"
  end

  def self.city_state(point)
    return "ANYWHERE" if point.nil? || (point.x == 0.0 && point.y == 0.0)
    city_state = {}
    l = first(:conditions => {:coords => point})
    city_state[:city] = l[:city]
    city_state[:state] = l[:state]
    city_state
  end

  def self.distance_between(locale_one, locale_two)
    #locale_one and locale_two must be points
    select = "ST_Distance(gg1, gg2)"
    from = "(SELECT ST_GeographyFromText('#{locale_one}') AS gg1, ST_GeographyFromText('#{locale_two}') AS gg2) AS foo"
    distance = Location.select(select).from(from)
    #1609.344 is how many meters are in a mile
    "%.2f" % (distance[0].st_distance.to_f/1609.344)
  end

  def self.check_unknown(cs)
    report = Report.first( :conditions => { :metric => "unknown_locations", :name => cs } )
    #i.e. if it's been tried 25 times, add it to the locations table.
    if report.value > 5
      city, state = cs.split(",")
      state = state.strip
      google_api_results = HTTParty.get("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=#{cs.gsub(/ /, "%20")}&sensor=true")
      geo_data = google_api_results.parsed_response
      lat = geo_data["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"]
      lng =  geo_data["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"]
      l = Location.new({ 
        :city => city,
        :state => state,
        :coords => "ST_GeographyFromText('POINT( #{lat} #{lng} )')",
        :cs => "#{city}, #{state}"
      })
      l.save
      Report.delete(report.id)
      return l
    else
      return false
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Are you sure the `cs` parameter even holds a value?

Comment: yes it is spliting City and State and entering that in

Comment: sorry i just removed a portion that i had added since it wasnt working... i added :cs => "#{city}, #{state}" because that wasnt being added... i think the error might be in       lat = geo_data["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"]
      lng =  geo_data["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"]

Comment: Do you need a comma in between `#{lat}` and `#{long}` in the postgres sql?

Comment: Your script works for me in `irb` (I cant test your persistance logic, though). Perhaps the problem lies somewhere in your model definition for `Location`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database columns are called `CORDS` but in the hash you pass to `Location.new`, you pass the key `:coords`. You also fail to pass a :`zip`.

Does the `Location` model define a different mapping?

Comment: I believe that i am pasing to Location.new not Level.new but i am a newbie at this...

Comment: Yes, thats correct. See how easy typos are? (Fixed)

Comment: i added my entire locations model to the post